# PCA output of Matlab's pca() function doesn't match manual calculation

Tags: pca, matlab

I try to calculate the PCA in my matrix and I use two ways for this:

1. PCA function

   ```
   [coeff, score, eigenvalues] = pca(M);
   ```
2. And for compare and understand the PCA calculus, I try to calculate step by step the PCA without the matlab function pca.

   ```
   %// first I "z-scored" my matrix
   X = zscore(M);
   %// second I calculate the covariance matrix
   %// this matrix is equals to the correlation matrix
   V = cov(X);
   %// Third, I calculate the eigenvalues(E) and eigenvectors(U)
   [U,E] = eig(V);
   ```

The `pca` function's eigenvalues are not equal to `E` and I think the columns of `U` are principal components and rows of `U` are variables and it's not equal to `coeff`.

So, I think that I don't understand how calculate the PCA of a matrix?

Comment: I don't use MATLAB often, but its `pca` function might not do a z-score first. The preliminary standardization is helpful for statistical applications, but other applications of PCA don't require any transformation so the standard MATLAB call might not include it.

Comment: I replace M by X in the pca function's and i don't found a equal result. My "manual" calculus have sense or not?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html says `pca(data)` centers the data. But you did z-standardization `X = zscore(M)`.  That is, center-then-scale operation.

Comment: Sushi, please edit your question to reflect changes you did after @EdM's comment (+1).

Comment: It would help if you could show a simple example that illustrates the problem, like a 3 x 3 matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `zscore` function. If I do a "manual" z-scoring in my matrix I find the same result as with `pca`:

```
M = [10,5,14;12,5,45;123,58,42];
%// "manual" zscore
stdr = std(M);
X = M./repmat(stdr,size(M,1),1);
%// "manual" PCA
V = cov(X);
[U,E] = eig(V);
%// with pca function
[coeff,score,eigenvalue] = pca(X);
```

`E` equals `eigenvalue` and `coeff` equals `U` so I'm ok, I think I understand how calculate a PCA.

Comment: If you run `cov(zscore(M))` you will get exactly the same output as with `cov(X)` (I checked), so I don't think that there is any problem with the `zscore` function. Your manual zscoring produces identical output.

Comment: The coeff result is sorted, maybe i don't pay attention at this before.